# How do I make my planet dimly lit but still habitable?

Tags: science-based, planets, atmosphere, solar-system

Currently I am making a solar system for a speculative evolution project, and I wanted my habitable planet to be really dark, while still being habitable (Preferably slightly colder of warmer then Earth). Currently no properties of the planet nor star have been set in stone, but I wish to have at least a K-Type star. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Really tall trees that block all sun from the ground?

Comment: How dark is "really dark"? And does this have to be planet-wide or a localized effect?

Comment: @sdfgeoff I am more thinking before life evolves, although I never considered that.

Comment: @Cadence dark enough to not be able to see, equivalent to the bottom of the ocean (Or just above it).  This has to be planet-wide.

Comment: Katze, I closed your question because it's a fundamental duplicate of the linked question. But I also note that your question is really broad and has very few specific details that would allow us to produce an objective best answer. If you feel my decision was inappropriate, please [edit] your question with details. A lot of details (this feels like you had an interesting idea and are asking us to flesh out the whole thing. Questions are expected to be specific.). As well as an explanation for why the previous post failed to meet your needs. Thanks.

Comment: That's going to be a tall order. Even the thickest terrestrial atmospheres - like Venus's or Titan's - only decrease light about 10-fold. A moonlit night, as bright as it is in comparison to your request, represents around a 10,000-fold reduction in light. You want something far stronger than that. (Have you considered setting your story under the ocean?)

Comment: @JBH that’s fine! I asked this question partially because I couldn’t find any other questions similar to it :)

Comment: Definitely considering the tree option now - it would allow both lightless and light(ful?) life